# uitableview cell selection on button action

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uibutton

My table view uses a custom class to create cells

MyCustomCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyCustomCell : UITableViewCell

@end
```

MyCustomCell.m

```
#import "MyCustomCell.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>


@implementation MyCustomCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self)
    {
        // Initialization code

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(5,4,80,80);
    self.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
    self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    float imgWidth =  self.imageView.image.size.width;
    if(imgWidth > 0)
    {
        self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(110,2,170,25);
        self.detailTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(110,18,200,25);
        self.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
        self.detailTextLabel.alpha = 0.0;
        self.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
        self.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.2314 green:.3490 blue:.5961 alpha:1.0];


    }
}

@end
```

and is use it like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


    MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {


        cell = [[MyCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        //cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;



    }

    CGFloat screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;

    if ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.f && screenHeight == 568.0f)
    {
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"select2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(SelectButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(110, 25, 63, 32);
        //btn.tag = indexPath.row;

        viewProfile = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        viewProfile.frame = CGRectMake(190, 25, 93, 32);
        //[viewProfile setTitle:@"View Profile" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [viewProfile setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"viewProfile@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [viewProfile addTarget:self action:@selector(viewProfileTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:viewProfile];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:btn];

    }

    else
    {

        UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"select.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(SelectButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        btn.frame = CGRectMake(110, 25, 63, 32);
        //btn.tag = indexPath.row;

        viewProfile = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        viewProfile.frame = CGRectMake(190, 25, 93, 32);
        //[viewProfile setTitle:@"View Profile" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [viewProfile setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"viewProfile.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [viewProfile addTarget:self action:@selector(viewProfileTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:viewProfile];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:btn];


       }

    return cell;

}
```

Now each cell contains two buttons which perform an action(I do not make action on cell tap but on button tap) as created like above

Now what i want is when a user taps a button(say select button) in a particular cell, that particular cell only should become highlighted or shaded or coloured and when user taps a button in another cell, that cell should become highlighted making the previous cell unhighlighted. I have tried storing previous and next indexpath's in 2 different variables but not able to work on them to achieve what i want.

```
- (void)SelectButtonTapped:(UIButton *)button
{


    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)button.superview.superview;

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [homeTable indexPathForCell:cell];

    // UITableViewCell *cell1 = [homeTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //currentSelection = indexPath.row;

    //MyCustomCell *cell1 = (MyCustomCell *)[homeTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [[homeTable delegate]tableView:homeTable didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

     //MyCustomCell *cell1 = (MyCustomCell *)[homeTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    /*if(currentSelection == 0)
    {
         [cell1 setSelected:YES animated:YES];
        currentSelection++;
    }
    else
    {
         [cell1 setSelected:YES  animated:YES];

    }*/
   // NSIndexPath *indexPath1 = [homeTable indexPathForCell:cell];

    NSLog(@"current===>%d",currentSelection);



    //[cell1 setSelected:NO animated:YES];

    //if(currentSelection == indexPath)




    //UIButton *clickButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    // NSIndexPath *indexPathHighlight = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:button.tag inSection:0];

    //button.tag = indexPathHighlight.row;





    //UITableViewCell *newCell = [homeTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPathHighlight];


    //if(newCell.selected == NO)
    //{
    //[newCell setSelected:YES animated:YES];
     //   [newCell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    //}
    //else
   // {
        //[newCell setSelected:NO animated:YES];
        //[newCell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:232.0f/255.0f green:237.0f/255.0f blue:240.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
    //}
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    MyCustomCell *cell1 = (MyCustomCell *)[homeTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell1.selectionStyle= UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;

}
```

You can look at my messy button action method. I have tried many options but with no success. Please help on this.

Comment: pasting complete code won't help, have you pointed out the place where you think the problem is? have you tried debugging it?

Comment: Yes i tried, what i am getting is when the button in cell is tapped that cell becomes highlighted but when i tap button in another cell that also becomes highlighted not making the previous cell unhighlighted and when i scroll the table view, all the highlighted cells come to normal unhighlighted state

Comment: can you post code of didSelectRow method.

Comment: i have edited my code with didSelectRow method

Comment: @user1845209 : I have added response comment in my answer, just check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncomment the line :

```
btn.tag = indexPath.row+1000;
```

Also change the cell selection style as

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue];
```

when create it.

In SelectButtonTapped method :

```
- (void)SelectButtonTapped:(UIButton *)button
{
  int buttonIndex = button.tag;

  for (int row = 0; row<numberOfRows; row++)
  {
    NSIndexPath indexPathHighlight = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];

    UITableViewCell *newCell = [yourTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPathHighlight];

    if (row == buttonIndex - 1000)
    {
        [newCell setSelected:YES animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [newCell setSelected:NO animated:YES];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: when i uncomment btn.tag = indexPath.row; and scroll table, compiler throws exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance here:

UILabel *lblTemp1 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    
        Home *tempHomeObj=(Home *)[profileArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *cellValue=(NSString *)tempHomeObj.userName;
        lblTemp1.text=cellValue;

Comment: @user1845209 Change the tag to some related one like indexPath.row+1000.. Because you may used the same tag for another element..

Comment: ok i tried your method but it makes all the cells highlighted i.e it does not make previous cell unhighlighted

Comment: @user1845209 Then you have to write a for loop for unhighlight previous cells or all other cells.. I don't know any other easy method..

Comment: is there any way to call didSelectRowAtIndexPath in my button action method?

Comment: @user1845209 That i don't know.. See my updated answer for unhighlight other cells..

Comment: hi anusha..i got it working thanx though there is a lil problem that the button on the cell also changes colour and it does not come to its normal state when some other button on other cell is tapped.can you help me in this?

Answer (score 2):

Lets think that your table has only one section and tag of your button be the row number of the corresponding cell.

In the button action

```
int rownumber = button.tag;
//print the rownumber and see if you are getting the correct value
UITableViewCell *cell = [tablename cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath     
indexPathForRow:rownumber inSection:0]];

[cell setHighlighted:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    MyCustomCell *cell1 = (MyCustomCell *)[homeTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell1.selectionStyle= UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
}
```

Comment: this will only do when tapped on area in cell except buttons..i have already tried this

Comment: is there any way to call didSelectRowAtIndexPath in my button action method?